# In Twillio Not able to send SMS, UNAUTHORIZED - The supplied credentials, if any, are not sufficient

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I'm trying to send an SMS from Twilio dashboard, but getting below error frequently. Just for information, earlier it was working.

Sharing detail error message as below:

> 401 - UNAUTHORIZED - The supplied credentials, if any, are not
> sufficient.

with details:

```
{
   "code":20003,
   "message":"Authenticate",
   "more_info":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003",
   "status":401
}
```

*Take a note: `s_id` and `authToken` were passed correctly.*

Thanks

We've tried to update configuration in message services by enabling Two factor authentication as which is required to send SMS from USA region.

Also updated settings for organisation type from solo proprietorship to incorporation.

Comment: The "more info" URL has quite a bunch of possible reasons, have you checked/ excluded all of them yet?

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for replying, I've checked possible reasons, such as verified sid, auth token but still i am getting same error, earlier it was working.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to ask the support team? This doesn't seem to be a coding related question.